# Compare two 2-dim feature vector to find out the similarity of these

Tags: vector, comparison, feature-extraction, list-comparison

i m trying to compare the similarity of two feature vector. In the activation is shape output (60000, 64) and the shape output for the new_activation is (10000, 64). I m looking for a way to find out how many of the vectors inside the new_activation are similar to vectors in the activation. how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

```
#put all the the training data in the activation layer
activation = feature_activation_model.predict(train_img)

print(activation.shape)


#########

#put the new or old data to compare their feature vectors
new_activation = feature_activation_model.predict(test_img)

print(new_activation.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is python code, I guess..

Well you need to find out what you mean by similar vector. Here you have a table of 60000 vectors of size 64 in activation (so vector are the lines ?), and a table of 10000 vectors of size 64 in new_activation.

I don't know what is your math problem here so I can't really help, but similarity between vectors could be defined as the norm of their difference. Let u and v be to vector of same size n, than if ||u-v|| is close to machine precision, we could same u and v are pretty much the same vectors